# Is copying from a std::map or std::set thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, stl, thread-safety, set

I know that multi-thread read access to an `std::se`t or `std::map` is safe, but what about doing copy operations like

```
std::map<int, int> node_info;
int node = 2;
int node_value;

if (node_info.find(node) != node_info.end())
   current_val = map_of_val[node].front();
```

I lock the maps when I am using `.push()` or `.pop()` for synchronized access, but my code is behaving erratically and I would like to know if know if this is causing instability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking on `push()` and `pop()` isn't enough. If one thread could be reading from the container while another is modifying it, *both* need to lock.