# Need to lock a copy of an stl::map of pointers while reading?

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, stl, thread-safety

I have an `stl::map<int, *msg> msg_container`, where `msg` is a class (not relevant here).

There are multiple threads adding to the global `msg_container`, with locks in place for synchronised access.

In a seperate thread, it needs to assess a local copy of `msg_container` at a particular time and perform checks on it. Pseudo-code as below

```
map<int, *msg> msg_container;
map<int, *msg> msg_container_copy;

if (appropriate_time_is_reached)
{
    msg_container_copy = msg_container;

    //perform functions on msg_container_copy
}
```

As per my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669480/is-copying-from-a-stdmap-or-stdset-thread-safe/17669533?noredirect=1#17669533), I know I will need to lock `msg_container` when reading, if there is a chance that other threads are adding to it.

Do I need to lock `msg_container_copy` when using it in this manner? It is local only to this thread, so there are no other threads that will be accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the necessity to lock the variable msg_container_copy if as you describe, "It is local only to this thread, so there are no other threads that will be accessing it."

By the way, I think the definition "`stl::map<int, *msg> msg_container;`" should be written as "`stl::map<int, msg *> msg_container;`" if msg is a class, so that msg * is a pointer type. It must be a typo.

Comment: the question arises because taking a copy of the map - means also taking a copy of the pointers (as far as I can be sure). Is it multiple access of a container, as opposed to multiple access of its elements, that causes thread un-safety?

Comment: @sccs Yes, that is why you should lock msg_container to prevent being accessing from other threads. But as you said, msg_container_copy is local to this thread, it won't be interupt when referencing without locking it.

Comment: @sccs The definition of a data race is when multiple simultaneous accesses are made to the same object, at least one of which is a modification. The elements of a container are distinct objects from the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lock to access `msg_container_copy` because no other thread can access it.

You might need a lock when dereferencing the pointers it contains, because they are shared with other threads. It depends what you do with those pointers.